# How to run bash script when eth0 came up from hibernate

Tags: linux, bash, hibernate, interface

I have following problem and I can not solve it: My Debian server should execute a Bash script as soon as eth0 came up from hibernate.

I have created a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Called when a eht0 interface comes up

if [ "$IFACE" = "eht0" ]; then
      /usr/local/sbin/omv_status_file.sh start_ifup
fi
```

The script is excecuted at boot / reboot but not at wakeup from hibernate.

Have anybody an idea how to get the script run when the network interface comes up at resume from hibernate? Thanks.

Comment: You could make a cron script that executes every 1 min or so.. The script 1st checks the status of eth0 and then carries out the task if eth0 is on the desired state

Comment: Thx for your comment, but that's not what I wanted . The script must run with network access directly after waking up.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem.

I created a bash script in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/`

The script is executed at wakeup from hibernate. It pings the network gateway. 
If the ping is successfully it execute the real script, otherwise it waits a second.

Question can be closed.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but as you can see, it's not really a programming Q of the `if/then/else` type ;-). You can accept your answer after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points. Good luck and keep posting (programming Qs ;-) ).